# Background image does not display on login button in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a login page hosted on SharePoint 2013. On login button,  background-image does not displayed in IE. Images are coming from webresource.axd. Although it is working fine in FireFox and Chrome browser. I used fiddler to see whether webresource are loading properly. I dont find any error over there. But not able to see the image. Rest of the things are working fine in IE as well except images are coming from webresource.axd are missing. 
Below is the C# code for login page button.

```
        objHTMLTableRow = new HtmlTableRow();

        // First Cell of Fourth Row
        //objHTMLTableCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        //objHTMLTableCell.InnerHtml = "&nbsp;";
        //objHTMLTableRow.Cells.Add(objHTMLTableCell);        // Add Cell to Row            

        //Second Cell of Fourth Row
        objHTMLTableCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        objHTMLTableCell.Attributes.Add("colspan", "2");
        objHTMLTableCell.Attributes["style"] = "vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;padding-left:24px;background-image:url(" + Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(com.mitchell.mic.webparts.LoginWebPart), @"com.mitchell.mic.webparts.Images.btn_bg_green.gif") + ");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:64px;";
        m_objLbtnLogin = new LinkButton();
        m_objLbtnLogin.ID = "LBtnLogin";
        m_objLbtnLogin.Text = m_sLoginButtonText;


        m_objLblBtnGreen = new Label();
        m_objLblBtnGreen.Controls.Add(m_objLbtnLogin);
        m_objLblBtnGreen.CssClass = "wpBtnRollOver";

        objHTMLTableCell.Controls.Add(m_objLblBtnGreen);
        m_objLbtnLogin.Click += new EventHandler(m_objLbtnLogin_Click);
        objHTMLTableRow.Cells.Add(objHTMLTableCell); // Add second cell to Fourth Row
        m_objHTMLTableLogin.Rows.Add(objHTMLTableRow);     // Add Fourth Row to Table
```

Below is the compiled HTML, taken form source.

```
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="198" height="150" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="wploginbox"><div onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034_LBtnLogin&#39;)" style="border:0px solid #FFFFFF;padding:0;margin:0;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="wploginform">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>Org ID:</span></td>
                                <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034$txtOrgID" type="text" value="40011" maxlength="20" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034_txtOrgID" class="wplogininputwhite" style="width:95px;" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>User ID:</span></td>
                                <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034$txtUserID" type="text" value="20090416" maxlength="20" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034_txtUserID" class="wplogininputwhite" style="width:95px;" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span>Password:</span></td>
                                <td style="padding-left:4px;"><input name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034$txtPassword" type="password" maxlength="10" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034_txtPassword" class="wplogininputwhite" style="width:95px;" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;"><span class="wploginform_rememberme"><input id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034_ctl19" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034$ctl19" checked="checked" /></span><span> Remember Me</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;padding-left:24px;background-image:url(/WebResource.axd?d=1RWHPAa3ATF4KY1H2DsfVI9zh7Bz9zyKV8YdpN-1UICCB0xbTxdefmWDROMREcZxTfk5zDruVVFp65oG13wHySv23q8xj6Li_vnUTvDX5yJ7gx3__LeWEaTh-lPDWxUD1PZJ1-E5DTuqr1mkM3B3aRyeYYDAuLCWgH9o5uYSSbyU_YfkP-H0s9ZyCx8yy4Y5n5TTkA2&amp;t=635752756671952932);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:64px;"><span class="wpBtnRollOver"><a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034_LBtnLogin" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034$LBtnLogin&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Login</a></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center;color:#035388;" colspan="2"><a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ff042241_1704_4e2b_97e4_a563d8044034_hypForgotPwd" href="http://www.qa.mymitchell.com/PasswordMgmt/ForgottenPassword.aspx?co=&amp;userid=&amp;popup=true" target="_blank">Forgot your password?</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: I am using ie9 and ie11

Comment: Please post the resulting (compiled) HTML that comes out on the page in place of your source.

Comment: Hi, I have posted the resulting HTML above, taken from page source.

Comment: Any help If someone can do ??